# URL List - Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I'll do the data import from my server to export to Google Storage, I have more than 30GB to upload to the new server.
One of the ways I found it is by creating a URL List https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list . The location I'm testing is http://gice.com.br/energyeasy/cf/GoogleCloud/url_list.php .  What I see is that everything seems to be correct, but Google has returned the error.

> Status: Failed
>
> Files: 0 of 0
>
> Bytes 0 B of 0 B
>
> UNKNOWN: (Showing 1 of 1 failures)
>
> Object: http_list_0
>
> Details: Task stalled too long.

The fields are separated by tab, first parameter is the location of the file, the second is the file size, and the third is using md5_file and encoding in base64_encode. I am using PHP. I'm following the instructions, but it's not clear why it does not work

Comment: Did you find solution of "Task stalled too long" issue?